# Is there a difference in CSS selectors `:enabled` vs `not(:disabled)`

Tags: css, css-selectors, browser-support

Is there a difference in behaviour or browser support for using the CSS3 selectors `:enabled` or `not(:disabled)`?

I expect them to be functionally identical, and as they are both CSS3 selectors, browser support should be identical too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference — `:not(:disabled)` can match elements that are *neither* `:enabled` nor `:disabled`. These are elements where enabled/disabled semantics simply don't apply, such as `div`, `p`, `ul`, etc.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#enableddisabled) confirms this:

> What constitutes an enabled state, a disabled state, and a user interface element is language-dependent. In a typical document most elements will be neither `:enabled` nor `:disabled`.

Interestingly, the same can't be said for `:checked` — there is no corresponding `:unchecked` pseudo-class, despite the fact that not all elements have checked/unchecked semantics either. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846075/css3-unchecked-pseudo-class).

If you're qualifying these pseudo-classes with a type selector (such as `input`, `select` or `textarea`) or a class selector, you probably don't have to worry about this. Still, it makes more sense to use `:enabled` than `:not(:disabled)`.

Browser support for the majority of level 3 pseudo-classes is indeed identical — there are no known browsers that support either `:enabled` or `:disabled` only. However, according to MDN it looks like Opera 9.0 and Safari 3.1 [don't support `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot#Browser_compatibility), although they do support [`:enabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:enabled#Browser_compatibility) and [`:disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled#Browser_compatibility), and some other features like substring-matching attribute selectors and the general sibling combinator `~` are supported in IE7 with some issues and a little bit better in IE8.

Comment: I had a feeling it wasn't simple; thanks for a great answer!