# Select all radio buttons not checked

Tags: css

It's possible to select the radio buttons that are checked

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked {
   // some style 
}
```

But is it possible to select all radio buttons that are not checked?

Comment: Have you tried `:not(:checked)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 :unchecked pseudo-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846075/css3-unchecked-pseudo-class)

Comment: For the person that closed this question. Let me know how this question can become more focused. Because to me this is pretty focused. It's a asking a single question around a specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, as there is no such thing called unchecked in css3 yet. As far as I'm aware.

```
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
    /* styles */
}
```