# What CSS selector syntax finds multiple pseudo classes on the same element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

What CSS selector finds all [unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846075/css3-unchecked-pseudo-class) *and* [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) checkboxes? Those links provide answers to how to find unchecked *or* disabled checkboxes, respectively, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493232/multiple-css-pseudo-classes) shows how to find an element with one pseudo-class and one pseudo-element, but I'm looking to find multiple pseudo classes on the same element.

I *think* the answer is to chain them without spaces (i.e., `input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked)`, and this *seems* to work, but I don't know how to tell if this is working correctly or doing something else and returning what I want by coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'this seems to work' - no it doesn't as it picks up those checkboxes that are checked. Put a :not in and you'll be OK.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked)
```

Here's a snippet showing the various combinations. cyan is what your code would select and pink is the one you actually want.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked+label {
  background: cyan;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked)+label {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" checked><label>Radio checked</label>
<input type="radio"><label>Radio unchecked not disabled</label>
<input type="checkbox"><label>Checkbox not checked not disabled</label>
<input type="checkbox" disabled><label>Checkbox not checked disabled</label>
<input type="checkbox" checked><label>Checkbox checked not disabled</label>
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled><label>Checkbox checked disabled</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You can combine psuedo-classes by putting them next to each other without whitespace. Note that the `*` isn't strictly needed here, but maybe helps show intent:

```css
*:not(:checked):disabled {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" /> <br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled/> <br>
<input type="checkbox" checked/> <br>
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled/>
```

Comment: Might be better to steal my example, since I'm specifically looking for checkboxes in my question body

Comment: You do need to select the correct input type otherwise you could end up selecting e.g. some radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As `:checked` and `:disabled` are *element attributes* you can alternatively use their attribute selector form instead of the pseudo selectors, but that would make your CSS a little less transparent.

**UPDATE**

As @Kaiido correctly commented, this solution did not account for checkboxes inside a `<fieldset disabled>`, making it not work properly. I adjusted the code to work with and without a parent `<fieldset>` either `disabled` or not. The *accepted* answer, however, does not work correctly (for now).

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:is(:not(:checked):disabled,
                          :not(:checked)[disabled],
                          :not([checked]):disabled,
                          :not([checked])[disabled]) {
  outline: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p>no fieldset</p>
<input type="checkbox"> <label>unchecked</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled> <label>unchecked disabled</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" checked> <label>checked</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled> <label>checked disabled</label><br>
<br>

<fieldset>
  <legend>fieldset</legend>
  <input type="checkbox"> <label>unchecked</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled> <label>unchecked disabled</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked> <label>checked</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked disabled> <label>checked disabled</label>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset disabled>
  <legend>fieldset disabled</legend>
  <input type="checkbox"> <label>unchecked</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled> <label>unchecked disabled</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked> <label>checked</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked disabled> <label>checked disabled</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Only the `disabled` attribute is reflected, you can't assume that `:not([checked])` equals `:not(:checked)`, and actually you can't even assume it for `disabled`, since `:disabled` can be inherited from `<fieldset disabled>` even for an `<input>` that would match `:not([disabled])`.

Comment: @Kaiido, you're right, I checked inside `<fieldset disabled>`. Unfortunately, this is also true for the accepted answer. Updated the answer to catch all options.